# Math class codename one

Tags: codenameone

Why is all the math not in one class in codenameone? This makes it so you need to go and check to see which Method is in which class. Not a big deal but does not seem to be logical. I am sure you have a great reason I just was interested to see what it is.

Answer (score 1):

The Math class in CN1 follows the CLDC11 API, whose Math class doesn't include all of the methods of JavaSE.  This made CN1 more easily portable to those devices.  Adding these methods in a separate class was just easier to port.

Now that J2ME is in the past, I don't see any reason why we can't move the Math class inline with the JavaSE Math class.  I have opened an RFE for this [here](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2105)